# IHttpClientFactory DI registration in .NET Framework with Autofac

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac, httpclientfactory

.NET Framework Version: 4.7.2
Autofac Version: 4.0.1.0

I want to register IHttpClientFactory in my Global.asax but I can't use services.AddHttpClient like in .net core. I need IHttpClientFactory as a dependency for a http client class of my own that I need to reference in my webapi project.

Is this even possible? And if yes, how is it done?

Comment: Create a service collection, invoke add http client extension and use autofac integration `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to populate your container and get a provider

Answer (score 10):

The required component are available in .Net Framework

Create a service collection, invoke add http client extension and use autofac integration `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to populate your container and get a provider

The following .Net Framework Unit Test is used to demonstrate what was mentioned above

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[TestClass]
public class HttpClientFactoryTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Create_HttpClientFactory() {
        var services = new ServiceCollection(); //Create a service collection
        services.AddHttpClient(); //invoke add http client extension

        //...add other services as needed

        //use autofac integration `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` 
        var providerFactory = new AutofacServiceProviderFactory();
        //to populate your container
        ContainerBuilder builder = providerFactory.CreateBuilder(services);

        //...configure builder as needed

        //and get a service provider
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = providerFactory.CreateServiceProvider(builder);

        IHttpClientFactory factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

        //OR Container
        ContainerBuilder builder2 = providerFactory.CreateBuilder(services);

        //...configure builder as needed

        IContainer container = builder2.Build();

        IHttpClientFactory factory2 = container.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>();
    }
}
```

and be easily reproduced in your Global.asax

Comment: My application is based on v4.6.1 and when I try to install the `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` in my application, it doesn't work, it throws an error saying that "Could not install package 'Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 7.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."